# How do I put line breaks in p:messages in a p:tooltip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, styles, tooltip

I am trying to put a line break between list of rules a password filed is supposed to have:

Hope this code would help you reproduce it on your local machines

My JSF form looks like:

```
<h:form id="passwordForm">
     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <p:password id="password1" value="#{testBean.password}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="This field cannot be left empty"
                    placeholder="Password">
        </p:password>
        <p:tooltip for="password1"  id="password1ToolTip"
                   hideEvent="focus"
                   rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('passwordForm:password1')}"
                   position="right" hideEffect="fade" showEffect="fade">
            <p:message for="password1"/>
        </p:tooltip>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

This is how my bean looks:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2016821444602021904L;


    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}", 
    message = "Password should contain minimum 8 characters, 1 Uppercase alphabet, 1 lower case alphabet and 1 special character")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password cannot be this short!")
    private String password;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

Based on a few answers on SO I have tried modifying the validation message by introducing special entity codes `&#13;` and `[![&#10;][1]][1]` as follows:

```
Password should contain&#13;Minimum 8 characters&#13;1 Uppercase alphabet&#13;&#10; 1 lower case alphabet and 1 special character
```

Note: This attached image might not show up in a few browsers
[image: This is how the the tooltip looks]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you're showing the message in an extra tooltip? Looks a bit strange.

Anyway, what you need is a `<br/>` where you want the line break and set `escape="false"` in your `p:message`.

message:

```
Password should contain&#13;Minimum 8 characters&#13;1 <br/> Uppercase Password...
```

xhtml:

```
<p:message for="password1" escape="false"/>
```

**UPDATE1:**

Thanks to Parkash Kumar for the additional info to improve the answer.

**UPDATE2:**

You could also use CSS and `/n` for a line break, then you need to apply:

```
#messages td { white-space: pre; }
```

to your CSS.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by extra tooltip?

Comment: If message is getting formed from bean then no need to escape it, just use the `<br />` tag within the message, where line break is required and set `escape` to `false` on `p:message` or `h:outputText` wrapped in between `p:tooltip`.

Comment: NickDiv, you could just use <p:message for="password" display="tooltip" />, see also: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml @ParkashKumar oh thx for the info, I didn't knew that, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the tips. I will try them out first thing in the morning. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Nick Div: Appreciate the help by accepting the answer will be great and useful for others as well. :p

Comment: @ParkashKumar Absolutely